# Python methods implemented in external modules - not recognized

Tags: python

I wrote a Python module which contains methods to be used in other modules. By doing some coding, in some situation Python can't see that methods when they're called from other modules with `methods_module.method()` syntax. What are the situations in which this scenario is possible?

Comment: Can you share a bit of code? Preferably the shortest piece of code (from your main module and the module containing the methods) that replicate the problem.

Answer (score 0):

It's a bit unclear what your question is, so it's rather hard to answer. However, if you have imported using the following syntax

```
from methods_module import method
```

then this does not expose `methods_module` to your program. Therefore `methods_module.method()` would not work.

Comment: I did import with `import method_module´, but it still won't see them.